# Can I get beyond SharePoint Throttling on External List without altering the threshold?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, external-list

The SharePoint throttle for External Lists has been met in my most recent attempt to connect securely to an external SQL Database with approximately 5000 records.  Of course, I get the correlation error message:  Database response throttled. Maximum number of rows that can be read through the database system utility is 2000.  I understand the message and know how to get beyond it by altering the threshold or turning it off.

My question therefore is; can I get beyond this constraint while maintaining the threshold?  First, I cannot use a filter in the original query.  I understand the need for a threshold, but I need all records available for search and a future request may involve a table with 200,000 records.  Note: I don’t require the list to pull back any records prior to invoking an HTML Form Web Part to filter results.

As an alternative, I have created a separate IIS port (let’s say 8080) on my test machine and created a quick .NET Web application to perform the search and retrieval on the DB with my records.  This works quite well.  Is anyone out there doing something similar?  Is there any danger of collisions with this port or any other IANA open port? Thanks!